# How to make Jquery plugins work with emberJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the Jquery [FlowType Plugin](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) to make responsive text on my page. Everything was working fine before I set up ember, now the plugin stopped functioning.

Javascript for plugin:

```
<script>
    $('p').flowtype({
        fontRatio: 10
    });

    $('h1').flowtype({
        minFont: 40,
        maxFont: 140,
        fontRatio: 6
    });
</script>
```

HTML (in ember template)

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
    <h1>Writers Week</h1>
</script>
```

Applictaion.js (Ember routes)

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('about');
})
```

After some research, I figured out that you need to wrap the plugins in ember js code, but I don't know how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the JQuery **after** your view is rendered. You can do that using `didInsertElement`.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this._super();

        this.$('p').flowtype({
            fontRatio: 10
        });

        this.$('h1').flowtype({
            minFont: 40,
            maxFont: 140,
            fontRatio: 6
        });
    }
})
```